# Expected value from one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I’m trying to calculate the expected value from a set of numbers. All the numbers are in 1 cell separated by commas and I can’t split them into different cells. Is there any way to calculate this from just one cell or do I need to spread them out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are all the numbers in one cell? Why can't you split them out? Excel has cells for a reason, and one of those is that there should only be one value per cell, so it can perform calculations.

Comment: I have almost 100 values and it would be really messy to have it spread out

Comment: Not sure what you expect from us. You don't specify what you want to calculate. Your question is very vague. Edit your question, provide a data sample and provide the expected result. Explain the logic of how you arrive at the expected result. Also state your Excel version, since there are a few new functions that you may or may not have, depending on your version. Again, edit your question to do that, don't post that in a comment. Leave a comment when you've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

One thought is that if you don't need to actually examine the inputs physically, then you can use `Text To Columns` to place them into real cells, but those columns of cells can be Hidden and so not create a "messy" view. Actually, even if you DO want to always have the full input visible. Then use formulas on the cell ranges to satisfy your needs.

If you must have none of that, there is a current way to turn each single string into discrete elements that Excel can use directly in many functions and formulas, though not as easily addressed individually as a range of cells would be, and that is:

```
=FILTERXML("<group><element>"  &  SUBSTITUTE(A1,  ",",  "</element><element>")  &  "</element></group>",  "/group/element")
```

I've used full words in the XML `<>`'s to make their relationships in to each other clearer. But most would replace them with `<a>` for `<group>` and `<b>` for `<element>`. They do this to be prissy, er... perhaps "terse"... but also for a very big reason though I doubt most realize it.

That is that it will only be allowed to produce an array of something like 6,000-ish characters before hitting an Excel limit. So the single character in the `<>` brackets mean only an overhead of seven characters to add to the bytes taken by the contents of each element while the above would use 12 extra, 19 in total, for each element. Your strings seem likely to be short enough that it would not be a problem, but good habits are good habits even if those folks don't realize they have one. And "especially" if they do realize it.

If one DOES have long enough strings to be cut off by the character limit, one can use string functions to take pieces of the string and put them into the formula and using `SPILL` tools one can actually end up getting completely around that. At a price in complexity, but not understanding.

In any case, `FILTERXML()` will do this for you without a great deal of trouble. Basically, it takes a string you build which is in the form of an XML expression and tears it apart for you as individual values.

Not only can it be used like you would as a part in a formula feeding into another part, it can be used to fill cells instead. As written above, it would fill rows in a single column downward. Wrap it with `TRANSPOSE()` and it will spread out in a single row across however many cells. And you can use even things like `INDEX()` with it, even using that to perhaps take every 9th value instead of all of them.

But in a short time, no more than a lifetime, we will all have Excel's 19 or so new functions to do string-to-array operations, and vice versa, and even array building, and this task will be utterly simple and direct. With no length limits or ways to get around them.

Answer (score 0):

Excel with an O365 license has a new function that is currently only available in the Beta/Insider preview. It is called `TEXTSPLIT()`. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7

Using this function, you could parse a cell that contains a list of numbers.

```
=TextSplit(A1,",")
```

By its very nature, a list of numbers separated by a delimiter character will be text. Therefore, splitting the value into separate values will also result in text. Adding a zero to the text will coerce the result to numbers.

```
=TextSplit(A1,",")+0
```

This command will spread out the results into as many cells as required, but you can feed the result into another function that expects a range, for example Sum() or Average()

```
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")+0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to split values from one cell to each cell? Try this method:

1. select the **Column**- **Data**- **Text to Columns**- open **Convert Text to Columns Wizard**:
   [image]
2. under **Convert Text to Columns Wizard**- select the **Delimited** option:
   [image]
3. check **Comma** option:
   [image]
4. select the **Data Format** and **Destination** you need- click **Finish**:
   [image]

[image]